# Storing a list of data in a list django

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am creating an upvoting system where the user upvotes, however to prevent a user from voting more than once I need to store a list of all users who have upvoted the post, I am using sqlite3 database, I would like to know how to go about storing these users in a list in my post model, I have tried several diffrent options but they havent worked.

Database: sqlite3
Python Version: 3.8
Django Version: 3.0.3

current attempt:

models.py:

```
class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

current code :

```
def up_vote(request, pk):
    current_user=request.user
    pk=Post.objects.get(pk)


    try:
        post_instance = Post.objects.get(pk) 
        upvote = Upvote(post=post_instance, user=current_user)
    except Upvote.DoesNotExist:
        post_instance = Post.objects.get(pk)
        upvote = Upvote(post=post_instance, user=current_user)
    return redirect(Post(pk))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have an `Upvote` model with a foreign key to the `Post` model. Take this as an example:

```
class Upvote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Once the user upvotes a post you create a row in the `Upvote` table. You can check if the user has already upvoted the post by using a try block:

```
try:
    upvote = Upvote.objects.get(post=some_post, user=some_user)
    # User has upvoted
    # Response accordingly
except Upvote.DoesNotExist:
    upvote = Upvote(post=some_post, user=some_user)
    # Create the upvote
```

**Edit**
Regarding your error, when you are creating or querying a new instance of a model with a foreign key, you should pass an instance of the foreign key, not the class itself. You are now:

```
upvote = Upvote(post=Post, user=current_user)
# Notice the Post
```

The `Post` is the definition of the class `Post`. What you should do is create/obtain an instance of the class `Post` and pass it along. such as:

```
post_instance = Post.objects.get(pk=2) # Or whatever query you might need to use or even creating a new post
upvote = Upvote(post=post_instance, user=current_user)
```

Comment: how do I create a foreign key to the Post model. I know it is probably simple but im new to the Django framework

Comment: If the post is located somewhere else, maybe in another app, you can use a string to give the path, for example, models.ForeignKey('myOtherApp.Post', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: Ok  i have just tried your solution and have got an error I will update my post now

Comment: thanks for the updated i just tried that and am now getting a type error of: non-iterable int object

Comment: @LukeAcko13 update your question with the log or code please

Answer (score 1):

For this type of data usually is best to create a new model, for example, called "Upvotes" which will have 3 fields:

```
class Upvotes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This way you will create a table that will contain all the users that have upvoted a comment and which comment they have upvoted, including the date and time.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, didnt think about that. I will try that now